# After redirect return to proxy url Node/browserSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, gulp, charles-proxy

I am trying to proxy the `asos.com` website for local dev work and would like to be able access to the site from `localhost:6046` and then intercept some of the js calls and make changes to the functionality of the site.

I realise, the idea of this doesn't really work, as if the site itselfs forwards to another url I my proxy won't be able to follow to the new URL.

```
browserSync.init({
    proxy: "www.asos.com/men",
    port: 6046,
    open: true,
    ui: false,
    ghostMode: false
});
```

But I wonder if there is some way to do this, with node or by any means at all?

Comment: I believe the only way to actually do this would be witha  reverse proxy using say charles?